# Strange and unexpected behaviour with Javascript mousedown, mouseup, and mouseover events

Tags: javascript, html

First time posting so be gentle :)

**I'm trying to achieve the following**: Have the mouse cursor colour over the blocks ONLY if the left mouse button is held down. If the left mouse button is not held down, then no colouring occurs.

I am achieving this by generating an array of divs, and attaching 3 event handlers to each one(mousedown, mouseup, and mouseover). The mousedown/mouseup event handlers toggle a global called activeMouse, and the mouseover event checks this global before colouring.

Something strange happens though. On every second click, if I hold down the left mouse button on a recently coloured block then move the cursor, the mouseover event will not fire and the mouse cursor shows the error symbol. Upon releasing the left mouse button, the mouseover event will fire but not the mouseup event. This causes an inversion where the colouring will occur if the button is not pressed. This can be reversed again by clicking on a coloured block again. Below is the code, along with a gif to show what I mean:

```
function generateGrid() {

    // Calc box width and height based on container dimension
    let boxWidth = Math.floor(containerWidth/10)
    let boxHeight = Math.floor(containerHeight/10)
    containerID.innerHTML = ''

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            let div = document.createElement("div")

            // rgb placeholder variables
            let rgb
            let r, r10
            let g, g10
            let b, b10

            // set box height, width, and colour
            div.style.width = boxWidth + "px"
            div.style.height = boxHeight + "px"
            div.style.background = defaultColour

            // MOUSE DOWN event handler
            div.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
                if (!e.button) activeMouse = true
                console.log(`MOUSE DOWN. ActiveMouse is: ${activeMouse}`)
            })

            // MOUSE UP event handler
            div.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
                if (!e.button) activeMouse = false
                console.log(`MOUSE UP. ActiveMouse is: ${activeMouse}`)
            })

            // MOUSE OVER event handler
            div.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                console.log(`MOUSE OVER`)
                if (activeMouse) {
                    // if default colour, apply random rgb
                    if (div.style.background == defaultColour) {
                        rgb = randomRGB()
                        r = rgb[0], g = rgb[1], b = rgb[2]
                        r10 = r*0.1, g10 = g*0.1, b10 =b*0.1
                        div.style.backgroundColor = colourRGB(r, g, b)
                    }
                    // if rgb exists, shade by 10%
                    else {                                  
                        rgb = shadeRGB(r, r10, g, g10, b, b10)
                        r = rgb[0], g = rgb[1], b = rgb[2]
                        div.style.backgroundColor = colourRGB(r, g, b)
                    }
                }                            
            })

            containerID.appendChild(div)
        }
    // start new row
    let jump = document.createElement("br")
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(jump)
    }
}
```

[Here's a gif showing the behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXV5Y.gif)

I have tried attaching the mouseup/mousedown event-handler to the "container" div encapsulating the grid, but the same effect occurs. I have also tried changing the mouseover to mouseenter, but the behaviour persists. I have tried removing all the rgb colouring code in the if/else statement, but this also doesn't change anything.

Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so strange behaviour at all, that's the way browsers handle selected items on a page. Because moving the mouse around while pressing left button you're selecting elements.

Note that this only happens if you click on an item colored on last action, only those that were selected.

Solution: Easy, deselect everything on mouse down (function included at the end of script).

```js
let containerID = document.querySelector('#container');
let containerWidth = 500;
let containerHeight = 500;
let defaultColour = 'white';
let activeMouse = false;
let button = false;
generateGrid();

function generateGrid() {

    // Calc box width and height based on container dimension
    let boxWidth = Math.floor(containerWidth/10)
    let boxHeight = Math.floor(containerHeight/10)
    containerID.innerHTML = ''

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            let div = document.createElement("div")

            // rgb placeholder variables
            let rgb
            let r, r10
            let g, g10
            let b, b10

            // set box height, width, and colour
            div.style.width = boxWidth + "px"
            div.style.height = boxHeight + "px"
            div.style.background = defaultColour

            // MOUSE DOWN event handler
            div.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
                // Deselect everything
                clearSelection();
                if (!e.button) activeMouse = true
                console.log(`MOUSE DOWN. ActiveMouse is: ${activeMouse}`)
            })

            // MOUSE UP event handler
            div.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
                if (!e.button) activeMouse = false
                console.log(`MOUSE UP. ActiveMouse is: ${activeMouse}`)
            })

            // MOUSE OVER event handler
            div.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                console.log(`MOUSE OVER`)
                if (activeMouse) {
                    // if default colour, apply random rgb
                    if (div.style.background == defaultColour) {
                        rgb = randomRGB()
                        r = rgb[0], g = rgb[1], b = rgb[2]
                        r10 = r*0.1, g10 = g*0.1, b10 =b*0.1
                        div.style.backgroundColor = colourRGB(r, g, b)
                    }
                    // if rgb exists, shade by 10%
                    else {                                  
                        rgb = shadeRGB(r, r10, g, g10, b, b10)
                        r = rgb[0], g = rgb[1], b = rgb[2]
                        div.style.backgroundColor = colourRGB(r, g, b)
                    }
                }                            
            })

            containerID.appendChild(div)
        }
    // start new row
    let jump = document.createElement("br")
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(jump)
    }
}
function randomRGB() {
    return [Math.random(0,255) * 255, Math.random(0,255) * 255, Math.random(0,255) * 255];
}
function shadeRGB(r, r0, g, g10, b, b10) {
    return randomRGB();
}
function colourRGB(r, g, b) {
    return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
}
function clearSelection() {
   if (window.getSelection) {window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();}
   else if (document.selection) {document.selection.empty();}
}
```

```css
body {
  background:#ddd;
  padding:20px;
}
#container {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background:#fff;
}
#container > div {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Note:** For future questions, please include all your relevant code, so we can reproduce the issue.